# Multiple Attachments with Swiftmailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I'm creating a form that allows multiple files to be uploaded.  The form field values and attachments are then to be emailed to certain address.  I'm using Swiftmailer to generate these emails.  I know how to attach a file with Swiftmailer, but I don't know how to attach multiple files.  Does anybody know whether this is possible using Swiftmailer?

Comment: UPDATE: SwiftMailer [is being replaced](https://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-swiftmailer) with [Symfony/Mailer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it's simply a matter of making multiple calls to `attach()`:

```
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('../../uploads/hocuradit/' . $attPath . $attA)); 
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('../../uploads/hocuradit/' . $attPath . $attB));
```

Source: http://groups.google.com/group/swiftmailer/browse_thread/thread/416b287591dfe931?fwc=1

Comment: To supply an alternative file name to your attachment you can use: `$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($filepath)->setFilename($mypreferredfilename))`